# How to disable Excel 2016 plugin?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I don't remember what I did last time to Excel 2016. I think it could be that I have copied an addon to the installation folder.

It is now preventing Excel from starting. It is now stuck with this screen:

[image]

Word, PowerPoint, Outlook all work fine at the moment.

Is there a quick solution other than reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

Start in Safe mode:
From [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-Office-safe-modes-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72#__toc312758060):

*Use User-Initiated Safe mode*

To start a Microsoft Office program in User-Initiated Safe mode:

**On the Microsoft Windows Start menu**

Click Start, point to All Programs, and then point to Microsoft Office.

Press and hold the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, and then click the name of the Microsoft Office program that you want to run.

**In the Command Prompt window**

At the command prompt, use the /safe option when you start the program.

To **stop** *User-Initiated Safe mode*, exit the program then start it again normally.